# Is it possible to make Android TV app work on Amazon Fire TV?

Tags: android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

Since the Android TV leanback library is apparently compatible with SDK level 17, which is what the Amazon Fire TV uses, I set the minimum SDK level on my Android TV app and installed it using ADB on my Fire TV. It actually works without any problems. However, it doesn't appear in the apps list in Settings, so I can only launch it through ADB. And when I tried to do a Live App Test in the Amazon Developer console, it won't even install.

Are there some settings or something I can change to make it work correctly? It would be a pity to not be able to use the leanback library since it does actually work, and since Amazon hasn't really provided anything equivalent to it.

Comment: BTW, as of FIRE OS 5 the FireTV will support the leanback library.

Comment: @boltup_im_coding Amazon said that, but if you use leanback, Fire tv (Fire OS 5.0.3) would not list your app even in application management.

Comment: @boltup_im_coding Doesnt look like this is the case. As of the most recent version of Fire OS which i think is 5.2 this is still a problem.

Comment: @Osiris355 but now sideloaded apps show up in the library, so is it still a problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It is definitely possible**. However, there are a few things that you need to take into account.

First of all, the Fire TV does not honor the `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` intent filter, so you need to use the standard `LAUNCHER` one. Moreover, you won't be able to see your application in the home screen before the app is actually published in the Amazon Store.

Other than this, you should not find many differences from, say, developing for the Nexus Player.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that sideloaded apps aren't shown on the home screen, but it wasn't even showing up in the apps list in Settings. However, now that I've changed the intent filter, it's showing up in the list like it should. I'll now try the Live App Test again.

Comment: I ended up also having to take the android.software.leanback requirement out of the manifest, but it appears to be working as a Live App Test now.

Comment: It turns out there are a couple more things that need to be done before Amazon will approve it. It needs to take the audio focus and register a media button receiver. Otherwise, if a music app is playing in the background when my app starts, the music continues to play and the play/pause buttons control the music instead of video playback in my app.

Comment: So you're saying you don't need to compile the Fire stick SDK in order to release an app on amazon market? would save so much time if this was possible : )

Answer (score 1):

Here's a topic from the Fire TV documentation that might be helpful: [How Fire TV Development Differs from Android TV Development](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-differences-from-android-tv-development).