# Fire OS App missing under Managed Installed Applications

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, amazon-fire-tv

After a lot of searching I cannot find the answer to this. My fire tv app was  rejected by Amazon because the app doesn't appear under settings > manage installed devices in Fire OS. What is odd is this is not an issue for Android TV and I can see it in the app manager in setting there. Any idea what I could be doing wrong for the fire tv devices? Amazon has been zero help.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check this related SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985239/is-it-possible-to-make-android-tv-app-work-on-amazon-fire-tv?rq=1), where in the OP also experienced the same error you encountered. It turns out, there are a couple more things that needs to be done before Amazon will approve it. Hope this information helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thanks. Looks like amazon still has some things to work out on honering the leanback intent. Its supposed to work now but doesn't. Amazon makes this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is amazon only supports part of the Android Leanback Support Library. How we are supposed to know everything it does or does not support is unknown to me and is a really poor implementation on Amazon's part.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-differences-from-android-tv-development
"Fire TV supports some but not all of Android’s Leanback Support Library. Fire TV uses TV-specific UI components from Leanback, and Leanback widgets will work, but if you tag an activity for the Leanback Launcher, the activity will not work. Specifically, Fire TV does not acknowledge the activity category CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER."

I would recommend being cautious of your reliance on android leanback support with fire tv which really hurts code reusablity for software developers. Your app will still work but you may be missing the entry in settings like my current issue. Hopefully Amazon adds better support for the leanback support library going forward.